# C# Forms database? Is it SQL Server....or just Access?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

This is a pretty simple question, but I'm learning C# and I'm wondering if when you add a `Local Database` to your project (The book I'm using is `Head First C#`) if it's a SQL Server database or just an Access database (or something else).

I'm using just the Windows forms to add a database, and it's filling a bunch of columns in with the names/id's/etc of a database I filled out. It was super easy to do (I can see why people like C# now) But I didn't know if this was an actual SQL Server database you could do inserts/updates and such with. Or something else entirely.

I forgot to mention this is VS 2012 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if you're using VS 2012, a [LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) database will be created.  With prior versions of Visual Studio, the database will be [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).

Comment: Yeah this is VS 2012 express. Can you do normal Querys and such on the database (and T-SQL methods) or no?